# Extract body from Lambda callback in node js

Tags: node.js, lambda, callback

I'm trying to extract the body from the callback returned from a Lambda fuction. I am calling the function using the code below:

```
    const pdfBuffer = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      lambda.invoke(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
          console.log('STACK ERROR IS' + err, err.stack)
          reject(err);
        } else {
          console.log('Returned DATA is: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
          resolve(data);
        }            
      });
    });

    Prescription.deletePrescription(programId);

    const returnedPDF = JSON.parse(pdfBuffer.Payload)

    response.status(200);
    response.set({
      'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
      'Content-Disposition': `attachment; filename="${filename}.pdf"`,
      'X-Publish-Filename': `"${filename}.pdf"`,
    });
    response.end(new Buffer(returnedPDF.body, 'binary'));
```

And the Lambda callback function looks like this:

```
   return callback(null, {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: data,
    isBase64Encoded: true,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
    },
   })
```

The data object I am getting back looks like this:

```
{"StatusCode":200,"ExecutedVersion":"$LATEST","Payload":"{\"statusCode\":200,\"body\":\"JVBERi0xLjQKJdPr6eEKMSAwIG9iago8PC9DcmVhdG9yIChDa=\",\"headers\":{\"Content-Type\":\"application/pdf\"}}"}
```

I've tried a number of things to get the body of this nested object? Including `JSON.parse()` as I thought that it was `stringified`, however I'm not having any luck.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: looks like you need to be doing `JSON.parse(pdfBuffer.Payload.body)`, and the actual body looks base64 encoded. If you want to get that out you'll need to do `new Buffer(whatever, 'base64').toString('utf8')`

Comment: @Catalyst it's PDF data so think it remains as is? ill try it and report back. Many thanks